# Display simulated data in chart

Tags: excel

I am wondering how I could chart the following data in a line chart in Excel:

[image]

In the chart below, 20 simulated data points NAV mo+1 are 20 possible values in the first month in the future (mo+1). The next set represents 20 simulated NAVs in the second month (mo+2).

The chart should look something like the one below:

[image]

Problem is my charts end up looking more like this:

[image]

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Don't you know the location of the chart button in Excel or what is the exact issue?

Comment: I am not sure how to set up the axes with these data so that they chart twenty different lines. So far, the charts always show one line with all the simulations added on the time axis.

Comment: I am using Excel 2007.

Answer (score 1):

There are default structures for each chart as defined by Microsoft:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/select-data-for-a-chart-HA102809318.aspx

However this is not necessarily sufficient. Sometimes you better edit the data source and its mapping manually. This is described here:

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-edit-a-charts-data-source-in-excel-2010.html

Comment: Yes, correct. The only reason I ask is that there are 12,000 data points which I would have to reformat. If there's any way around it, this would be great.

Comment: Did you try the manual mapping? The series name is the column header (e.g. B2) and the series value is the column below that (e.g. B2:B22). This needs to be done manually for each column.

Comment: I tried to edit the data manually. Will investigate this further. Thanks for your inputs.